# How to center logo in navbar when there's another element in the navbar also?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

In my navigation bar there is  a logo which should be centered, and a menu button image (3 lines) which should be floated left. I've gotten the menu button to float left but just cannot seem to get the logo to be in the exact center of navbar, it's always a bit to the right.

I've tried puttin them both in divs and setting div width to 50%, then float the image left so it makes it centered but no luck.

HTML:

```
<div id="resp-navbar">
    <div id="resp-nav-contents">
        <img id="exp-menu-img" src="3lines.png">
        <img id="resp-logo" src="MSLOGO.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#resp-navbar{
    height: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:51;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #afafaf;

}   

#resp-nav-contents{
    min-width: 300px;
}

#exp-menu-img{
    height: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    opacity: 0.4;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#resp-logo{
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    display: inline;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added: `left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto;` to `#resp-logo`

```css
#resp-navbar{
    height: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:51;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #afafaf;

}   

#resp-nav-contents{
    min-width: 300px;
}

#exp-menu-img{
    height: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    opacity: 0.4;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#resp-logo {
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    display: inline;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="resp-navbar">
    <div id="resp-nav-contents">
        <img id="exp-menu-img" src="https://placehold.it/20x20">
        <img id="resp-logo" src="https://placehold.it/500x100">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the menu icon as `position: absolute;` and normalize the rest

Answer (score 1):

Use the following which may help

```
<div id="resp-navvar>
    <img id="exp-menu-img" src="3lines.png">
    <img id="resp-logo" src="MSLOGO.jpg">
```

```
#resp-logo {
positions:absolute;
left:50%;
Transform:translate(-50%);
```

Width- custom, height- custom 
    }

Don’t forget to put the root div position to relative if things don’t work

Answer (score 0):

Remove these from #resp-logo

> position: absolute; display: inline;

Or You can force it to center using margins.